# Annual forecasting using ARIMA in R

Tags: r, arima

I am trying to forecast the value for the next 5 years (2017 to 2022).

Here is the sample city-wise historical data:

```
City_Name       Year    Values
Chandler City   2012    19939
Chandler City   2013    19251
Chandler City   2014    19672
Chandler City   2015    19824
Chandler City   2016    19326
```

Here is the code which I have tried using R:

```
Age_Incomedata_1 = ts(city_aggregated[,3],start = c(2012),end = c(2016),frequency = 1000)
plot(Age_Incomedata_1, xlab='Years', ylab = 'Values')
library(forecast)

ARIMAfit = auto.arima(log10(Age_Incomedata_1), approximation=FALSE,trace=FALSE)
(forecast(ARIMAfit))
summary(ARIMAfit)

par(mfrow = c(1,1))
pred = predict(ARIMAfit, n.ahead = 36)
pred
plot(Age_Incomedata_1,type='l',xlim=c(2012,2022),ylim=c(1,30000),xlab = 'Year',ylab = 'Values')
lines((pred$pred),col='blue')
lines(10^(pred$pred+2*pred$se),col='orange')
lines(10^(pred$pred-2*pred$se),col='orange')
```

I don't have clue whether I am on the right path.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.